# Leaflet js - How can I change marker icon dynamically according to some conditions present in the database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, leaflet, maps, google-maps-markers

I have a list of places in a MySql database (with id, latitude, longitude, counter, timestamp). To add them to the map I make an asynchronous call to a php file where there is a search query. Places are displayed correctly on a map with Leaflet Js.

For each place I have a popup where there is a button with a data-id that refers to the id of the place present in the database. Clicking increases a numeric field.
I did this so as to have the field with the timestamp always updated.

This button is used to specify that the user is in that specific place.

Once pressed I would like the current icon to change to a special one and stay that way for at least 1 hour. If in the meantime other users press the button the time must not be added, but the limit remains 1 hour. After 1 hour the standard icon returns.

How can I achieve this? Thank you so much for the advice!

I tried saving the current timestamp with the one saved in the database, but with poor results..

Comment: I think some code would improve this question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.